# Getting EL variable properties in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, el, springsource

I'm using Eclipse/Spring source to edit JSP tags and EL. If I want to check what all the properties of a variable are is there a way to do this? Or even find out which file is generating the variable that's passed in. I'm thinking something along the lines of firebug for Javascript, where you can select an object and drill-down to get it's properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't support EL autocomplete yet. It isn't that smart yet. [IntelliJ Ultimate Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) supports it and [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) supports it as well, but both are not free (when talking about JSP/EL development).

The [JBoss Tools](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CodeAssistinJBossToolsXMLandJSPXHTMLEditors) Eclipse plugin supports it to a certain degree, only for implicit/predefinied EL objects, but not for custom ones which you've put as attribute in request/session/application scope yourself.

Comment: Now that it's 4 years later, is Eclipse smart enough yet?  :)

Comment: @Matt: Yep. It's even much better when you install JBoss Tools. Check this answer for an how to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057346

Comment: Sweet. Once JBoss is installed, what do I need to do within my JSP to tell content assist what the class of my bean is that I'm referencing with EL? I can't find documentation on this...