# How do I Install JBoss AS / WildFly Server in Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, application-server

When I went to the "new server wizard" I can't find the category for JBoss AS.

When I clicked "Download new server adapter" I don't get any JBoss AS adapter in the list.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Install the most recent [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/).

- Go to *Help > Install New Software*.
- Set *Work with* to the following URL depending on Eclipse version:

  - 4.8+ (Photon): https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/
  - 4.7 (Oxygen): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/oxygen/stable/updates/
  - 4.6 (Neon): https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/
  - 4.5 (Mars): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/mars/stable/updates/
  - 4.4 (Luna): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/
  - 4.3 (Kepler): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/
  - 4.2 (Juno):   http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/
  - 3.7 (Indigo): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/indigo/
  - 3.6 (Helios): http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- In the results, make sure that you've *Group items by catagory* checked and then select *Web and Java EE development* somewhere near the bottom.
- *Next*, etc, *Finish*.

[image: Installing JBoss Tools in Eclipse 2021-03 (Photon)]

This will get you the JBoss-provided AS and EAP server plugins, along with several easing JSF development plugins, such as EL autocompletion.

#### See also:

- [The BalusC Code - JSF 2.3 tutorial - Integrating WildFly in Eclipse](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html#IntegratingNewServerInEclipse)
- [EL proposals / autocomplete / code assist in Facelets with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276254/el-proposals-autocomplete-code-assist-in-facelets-with-eclipse)
- [show JSF EL call hierarchy in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901871/show-jsf-el-call-hierarchy-in-eclipse/)
- [Properties of new tags using composite component are not displayed by Eclipse auto complete shortcurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505264/properties-of-new-tags-using-composite-component-are-not-displayed-by-eclipse-au/)

Comment: Thanks, I cant vote at the time but I will give you my vote as soon I can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The url mentioned before wasn't working for me. The following url worked in eclipse's installer: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/ Also found a link describing this in more detail: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_2.html