# EL proposals / autocomplete / code assist in Facelets with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, el

I tried to activate EL proposals in a Facelets page, but when I hit Ctrl+Space, it doesn't work. I managed to activate JSF tag proposals thank to other questions, but EL proposals aren't working.

How can I activate this feature in Eclipse? Is it a known issue?

For example:

```
<h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{Ctrl+Space not working!}"/>
```

Comment: Facelets (XHTML) is the successor of JSP. I believe you're talking about EL proposals instead of JSP proposals, right? I've fixed the terminology.

Comment: A similar question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml

Comment: And here, for tag autocompletion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204807/how-to-see-docs-for-jsf-facelets-elements-in-eclipse

Comment: Thank you for correction! I was speaking about facelets in fact! I tried it and it works good. I noticed that Autocompletion is not working for facesContext.ctrl+space. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: If you are interested in auto-complete for Spring beans, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933757/el-autocomplete-code-assist-with-eclipse-and-spring-beans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't support this out the box. Even the support in JSP is very limited. Only the properties of `<jsp:useBean>` and managed beans hardcoded as `<managed-bean>` in `faces-config.xml` are available by autocomplete. There are however plugins which supports EL autocomplete on `@ManagedBean` and `@Named` beans.

For example, the [JBoss Tools plugin](https://tools.jboss.org) (specifically the CDI feature) which can be installed as described here: [How do I Install JBoss AS / WildFly Server in Eclipse for Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057328/how-do-i-install-jboss-6-in-eclipse-helios-jee/4057346#4057346).

[image]

*(which has in its current 3.2.0 version unicode bugs, as you see above in the rightmost window)*

You can even use Ctrl+Click on the managed bean name `#{bean}` in an EL expression in Facelets file to navigate to the concrete backing bean class. You can also use Ctrl+Shift+G on the managed bean method in a backing bean class to find all references to the particular property or action in Facelets files.

The [Aptana plugin](http://www.aptana.com/) is told to work fine for EL proposals in JSPs, but I am not sure for Facelets. I didn't had good experiences with installing and configuring the plugin for JSP some years ago.

#### See also:

- [Properties of new tags using composite component are not displayed by Eclipse auto complete shortcurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505264/properties-of-new-tags-using-composite-component-are-not-displayed-by-eclipse-au/)

Comment: Yeah. In Indigo 3.4.0 JBOSS Tools Plugin works with @ annotations too.Thank you Balusc

Comment: JBOSS Tools Plugin working very slow in eclipse Kepler

Comment: You need to select only the CDI feature. The rest is irrelevant and indeed hoggy.