# Eclipse code assist in EL using annotations

Tags: eclipse, jsf, el

Is there any possibility to access list of managed beans using Ctrl+Space within a EL pattern **#{hit Ctrl+Space here}** managed beans defied ***with annotation*** in some jar files from my Eclipse classpath (Web app libraries) ?

It works if I will defined manually within web-app faces-config.xml

My environment is:

1. Centos 6.4 x64
2. Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1
3. JSF Mojara 2.2
4. Primefaces 4.0 RC

Any help is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [EL proposals in Facelets with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276254/el-proposals-in-facelets-with-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it's related with other version of jsf and eclipse.

Comment: In other words, you tried JBoss Tools, but it doesn't work for you? That's strange. It has always worked for me in all JSF 2.x and Eclipse 3.x/4.x versions. You may want to update the question to reflect the problem you're facing with JBoss Tools.

Comment: According to related answers, TLD code assist works fine and also EL cod assist for project managed bens classes with annotation but for managed beans with annotation packaged into jar file within web app library does not.

Comment: I've raised following issue - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428585