# Properties of new tags using composite component are not displayed by Eclipse auto complete shortcurt

Tags: eclipse, jsf, attributes, composite-component, code-completion

I have developed composite components using JSF 2.0 in Eclipse. I've been putting my XHTML tag files inside `resources` folder.

When I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> in keyboard, the property of the tag are not displayed.

I found some tips told to install "Jboss tools" but didn't work.

```xhtml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value"/>
        <cc:attribute name="label"/>
        <cc:attribute name="masculino" default="true"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.attrs.value}" label="#{cc.attrs.label}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}"
                          itemLabel="#{cc.attrs.masculino ? lbl['LABEL.TODOS'] : lbl['LABEL.TODAS']}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="#{lbl['LABEL.SIM']}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="#{lbl['LABEL.NAO']}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>                                  
    </cc:implementation>

</html>
```

Above is one example of one tag created.

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: No, I'm still waiting for the solution

Comment: @user3503888 try updating your eclipse version

Comment: @RohitGaikwad to what version?

Answer (score 6):

JSF 2.x Facelets support is integrated in "[Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)" (note the **Enterprise**, thus not "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"), since Eclipse Helios (version 3.6, released June 2010). You need to ensure that the *JavaServer Faces* facet is enabled in *Project Facets* section of project's properties and is set to a minimum of version 2.0.

[image]

This is usually configureable during in new *Dynamic Web Project* wizard, but when importing non-Eclipse projects or creating non-*Dynamic Web Project* projects (e.g. Maven archetypes), then you need to manually check/add it.

Once integrated, JSF tag autocomplete is by default available on `java.sun.com` XML namespace.

[image]

The new `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace isn't recognized by default (currently tested Eclipse version is Luna SR2).

[image]

The new `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace will only work if you've added a physical JSF 2.2 implementation to build path in flavor of a full fledged Java EE container having JSF 2.2 in its modules, integrated via a decent server plugin and set as *Targeted Runtimes* in project's properties, or a concrete JSF 2.2 implementation JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` in case of Tomcat and clones (or by adding it as a Maven dependency).

[image]

It only still doesn't recognize composites in the new XML namespace. When changing back to `java.sun.com`, code completion of composite component tags is back, but code completion of attributes on those tags is not available.

[image]

Then I installed [JBoss Tools 4.2.3 for Eclipse Luna](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/4.2.3.Final.html) and enabled the *JBoss Tools Knowledge Base* in project's properties.

[image]

After closing and reopening the Facelet (so JBoss builtin HTML editor gets opened; you can set/configure the editor used by rightclick, *Open With*), and switching to the *Source* tab (please don't use *Visual* editor, this is a disaster), I finally got code completion of attribtues on composite components.

[image]

Only the `xmlns.jcp.org` still didn't work. It's an Eclipse specific issue and probably already fixed in Mars or newer. You can always hide the composite namespace behind a custom XML namespace as below:

`/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2"
>
    <namespace>http://example.com/my</namespace>
    <composite-library-name>components</composite-library-name>
</facelet-taglib>
```

`/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[image]

So, summarized:

- Enable JSF project facet in project's properties for code completion on composite tags.
- Install JBoss Tools for code completion on attribtues in composite tags.
- Enable JBoss Tools Knowledge base in project's properties.
- Have a physical JSF 2.2 impl JAR in buildpath for `xmlns.jcp.org` support on standard tags.
- Use `java.sun.com` XML namespace domain or a custom taglib (or a newer Eclipse version) on composite tags.

Comment: As you said, in Luna version the new namespace still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Eclipse Mars with Java EE package, Hibernate tools and Spring IDE and I just checked it works out of the box.

Make sure your component is under `webapp/resources/YOUR_COMP_NAME`.

**Ignore this, see edition below:** <del>Review your header namespace for `composite`, in your sample code you have</del>

```
xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
```

<del>but in my code I have</del>

```
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
```

<del>It doesn't mind whether you use `cc` pr `composite` prefix, but as you can see, the URL is diferent. See [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html)</del>

Finally, when you use this composite into any xhtml page, include it as follows:

```
xmlns:prefix="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/YOUR_COMP_NAME"
```

This way, when you write in eclipse `<prefix:` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> it will show you the list of components you have.

## Edit

I have just realized that `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite` is the new URL in substitution of `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite`, so I changed it in my code and it already works.