# No code completion in EL for Facelets files

Tags: eclipse, jsf, el, facelets, code-completion

I'm using the Eclipse Neon with Maven repos for JSF project with JPA, the controller that I've created is not showing in the auto complete for any tag attributes in Facelets.

For example:

```
<p:inputText value="" />
```

On the "value" should show the autocomplete with the controller that I have, but for some reason is not showing.
But if I type it manually, it works fine when I run on the tomcat server, so its not a problem on the class itself.

I copied everything from my last JSF project, I mean the configurations and the `pom.xml` and it's working on this one, but not on the new project.

Comment: check if you have all the relevant plugins. Which ones can be found using google

Comment: Hello Kukeltje, thank you for your answer. i'm using exactly the same plugins from my last project that worked fine.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought you switched IDE from e.g. Mars to Neon. Then I have no clue other than that maybe some project facets are not enabled now

Comment: The most strange thing is: both projects (the old and the new) are set on my Eclipse workspace, one is working fine, the other one no..

Comment: Facets are turned on/off per project

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27505264

Comment: Hello BalusC, thank you for you answer and for editing my question, helped alot. I tried also but still not working, i will create everything from scratch and see if it helps.

Comment: Is your file open with the roght JSF editor from Eclipse Java EE development tools? Try doing a right-click > open with to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason already.

When you create by Maven like me, you need to go to your Eclipse, RIGHT CLICK on your project > Configure > ADD JSF Capabilities.

Eclipse will create all needed files for auto completition on the facelets files.

Thank you for the help guys!