# Improving my JSF 2.0 development enviroment

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I was looking around the web, trying to find some drag/drop visual builder for my JSF pages in eclipse Helios. Unfortunately i did not find it.

Meanwhile i discovered that if i open my JSF pages with the built in JSP editor, i get the auto suggest feature. I was happy for that, but then i noticed some estrange warning that looks like this:

[image]

My Hello World app works perfectly, but i have a few doubts that if i could clear i would work more comfortable:

-Why that warning?(I thought JSF 2.0 need no navigation mamping and putting the name of the page we want to go to in the action attribute is enough)

-Is the reason for this warning that i am opening the page with the JSP editor?

-Do you know any drag/drop visual builder for JSF i can use with eclipse?

-What editor do you often use for your JSF pages? And what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *-Why that warning?(I thought JSF 2.0 need no navigation mamping and putting the name of the page we want to go to in the action attribute is enough)*

No idea. It's legitimately valid. Also in JSF 1.2 by the way (which in turn indeed requires a navigation case in `faces-config.xml`).

---

> *-Is the reason for this warning that i am opening the page with the JSP editor?*

No idea. Perhaps it's because Eclipse still thinks you're developing JSF 1.2. That the JSP editor is being used for Facelets is not a good sign in any way.

---

> *-Do you know any drag/drop visual builder for JSF i can use with eclipse?*

No idea. I don't drag'n'drop code. I just write code.

---

> *-What editor do you often use for your JSF pages?*

[Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) with [Glassfish plugin for Facelets support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204807/how-to-see-docs-for-jsf-facelets-elements-in-eclipse) and [JBoss Tools plugin for EL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276254/el-proposals-in-facelets-with-eclipse).

---

> *And what do you recommend?*

I won't post subjective answers. Fact is that I used Eclipse since 2003 and I tried Netbeans at least twice, once around 2004 and once around 2008, but each time I uninstalled it after trying for 5 minutes.

Comment: Would you please explain a little bit that why you uninstalled it after 5 minutes?Because it is also considered a good IDE.

Comment: @Adnan, I don't there is a need to explain whether Netbeans is good or not. It is subjective to a developer's needs. But if you want a hint pertaining to the originally posted question, take a look at [Netbeans Bug 169820](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169820). In my opinion, revoking VWP and Woodstock after pushing it in the first place is not a sign of a good IDE.

Comment: @BalusC I checked the config file, and also tried to create the dynamic web project ussing the wizzard, all indicates that i am ussing JSF 2.0 I think the reason is that i open with JSP editor, when i open with HTML editor i don't see that warning(But also i don't have the auto suggest feature). I thought about disabling that warning in the prefferences, but i don't know if is that a good idea, since maybe in the future it can advice me when i really need it. What do you think, is it ok to turn off that warning?

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper isn't the most fantastic Java IDE, but it has a visual editor for JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

> -What editor do you often use for your JSF pages? And what do you recommend?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for all JEE 6 stuff. But for all features you need the full paid version.

Answer (score -2):

The warning is because you are supposed to define the action like this:

```
#{bean.Action}
```

For this you need a method in your bean to process the command sent from the user interface. Typically these methods need to be a public String, and if you want to return the user to the same page as they were on you can just return a null object. If you want to send the user to a different page based on successful login or not you can return a string which represents the navigation string which you need to define in your faces-config.xml.

I use NetBeans for editing and deploying JSF applications. I have my NetBeans set up with auto-deploy to my test server which makes my testing really fast and easy.

Comment: I tried this: `<h:commandButton value="LOG IN" action="#{usermb.redirect}"/>` and in my managed bean i have this: `public String getRedirect() {
  return "Welcome";}` (This is a demo app not a real login, i don't want to add nothing to the faces-config.xml)
  But i get an exception that says: `javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @27,65 action="#{usermb.redirect()}": Method redirect not found` I don't understand where is the mistake.

Comment: I did what you said, but i can't redirect. Why is that?

Comment: Do not use javabean's method names on the action methods. So in other words scratch the "getRedirect" and rename it to just redirect.

Comment: Ops yes, silly mistake. By The way, NetBeans is a good tool i used it in the past, but i must work with eclipse, thats why i asked for the editor for eclipse. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's legitimately valid to define the outcome value straight in the `action` attribute instead of having it returned by a method.