# Eclipse (with JSF) code assistance (auto code hinting) problem

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jsf-2, code-hinting

I am doing a JSF project in Eclipse (Helios) and I enabled the JSF facet for my project.

Code assistance (code hinting) works for the JSF tags but not for the attributes.

Say, if I type the following then the all possible tags are displayed, that is fine.

```
<h:
```

But, if I type the following and press the space bar, no code hinting for attributes appears:

```
<h:graphicImage
```

I guess that Eclipse must have this feature (Netbeans is having similar feature) but I am missing something.

Please anyone tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204807/how-to-see-docs-for-jsf-facelets-elements-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the TLD reference (Eg. `html_basic.tld`) to the Eclipse project settings.  This will allow Eclipse to reference the TLD file to provide autocomplete functionality.

A better explanation of what to do can be found here:

[Eclipse autocomplete (content assist) with facelets (jsf) and xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml)

Comment: Where to get the TLD files, and how to install them? (The links in the suggested thread no longer working)

Comment: @MISS_DUKE, If a Google search can't find them on the web then you should be able to find them in the JAR files of the JSF implementation or the component libraries.  (Eg. `jsf-impl.jar` has `html_basic.tld` and `jsf_core.tld`)

Comment: Thanks, I have now put the tld files in the WEB-INF/tlds folder, and able to manually open the TLD files in the Eclipse IDE and refer the tags (it is really useful). But the Eclipse IDE itself is not making any hints for the tag attributed even now. What may be the reason for this?