# Using Eclipse Indigo for JSF 2.0 components

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, eclipse-indigo

Installed the Web Tools Platform 3.3.0 plugin for Eclipse but components are not available in the pallete. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [JBoss Tools 3.3](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3) only the Web and Java EE Web Development

this is how it will look like... [Visual Web Tools](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.1/html/Beginners_Guide/chap-Beginners_Guide-Java_Web_EE_and_Standard_Edition_SE_Plug_Ins.html#sect-Beginners_Guide-Java_Web_EE_and_Standard_Edition_SE_Plug_Ins-Visual_Web_Tools)

[Here is a BalusC answer with screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057346/617373)

Comment: In Netbeans there is... and I think in Intellij IDEA too

Comment: only code completion , no visual designer for prime faces in eclipse... http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15567&p=47460&hilit=eclipse%20plugin#p47460    http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3421&p=15697&hilit=eclipse%20plugin#p15697