# Configure Eclipse to resolve css classes declared in a facelets template

Tags: css, eclipse, jsf, autocomplete, facelets

Is there a way to do that? I mean, I want to declare some css classes (either by using style tag or importing a .css resource) and be able to see those imported classes when using autocomplete in a templated view. i.e:

/resources/css/style.css:

```
    .class1{ display: none; }
```

/views/template.xhtml:

```
   (...)
   <head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
   </head>
   (...)
```

view.xhtml:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/views/template.xhtml">
      (...)
      <h:outputText value="HiddenValue" styleClass="<CTRL+SPACE should show class1>"/>
      (...)
    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss Tools is capable of this (and many more).

How to install it is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057328/how-do-i-install-jboss-6-in-eclipse-helios-java-ee/4057346#4057346).

Comment: Thanks for the reply BalusC =). Sadly, I already have JBoss Tools installed but this feature is not there (or I cant find it). Are you sure about it?. 
Eclipse 4.3
Jboss Tools JSF 3.5.0