# How do i configure Eclipse to have a tooltip for JSF?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tooltip

I want my eclipse to have a tooltip popup every time i hover my mouse over a JSF element,
Like if i put my mouse over FacesContext , I want to have information about that element.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Install JBoss Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057346/). It also supports that on attributes. It even offers autocomplete lists on tags, attribtues, EL expressions, JS functions and CSS classes.

Comment: Can i use it with tomcat ?

Comment: It doesn't require a JBoss server at all. It just also bundles JBoss server plugin so that you can manage it from inside Eclipse.