# show JSF EL call hierarchy in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, el

Is there any way to get the call hierarchy of a JSF bean method including Expression Language calls in eclipse?

I got a simple bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped 
public class MyBean {
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And a simple JSF page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.demo}" />
```

With a CTRL click on #{myBean.demo} eclipse shows the getter.

But the call hierarchy for getHello() does not show the EL call.

Is there a way to see if a getter is used in any JSF page?

Comment: I guess not, because they are actually called at Runtime via Reflection.

Comment: There are errors in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/) (for Java EE+Web) supports it. You can get it in Eclipse Luna (4.4.x) by *Help > Install New Software* and then entering the URL of [this update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/). In the list of available plugins components, scroll to the bottom and pick the option *"JBoss Web and Java EE Development"* (the remainder is not relevant for Java EE web dev).

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll give it a try.

Comment: For additional install/config instructions, see also http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2014/10/jsf-22-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-wildfly.html#InstallJBossTools It also ships with a visual editor which you really want to disable.