# "Visual Page Editor has experimental support for Windows 64-bit"

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss

I am using Eclipse Luna and JBoss AS 7. When I create a JSP page in Eclipse, then I get the below error:

[image]

I changed my server to Tomcat 7, still I am getting the same error.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Same problem and solution for my case: Eclipse Mars, Windows 10 x64, JBoss Tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That visual page editor is part of [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org) plugin which you installed in order to be able to [integrate and use JBoss AS server in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057328/how-do-i-install-jboss-as-wildfly-server-in-eclipse-for-java-ee).

You don't need it. It's not only experimental, but generally visual page editors just doesn't work when you want to end up with quality code. Just click the red cross at the right bottom corner and then click the *Source* tab and finally close the *Palette* tab. This is fortunately an one-time thing. It will stay away when you create new JSP pages.

[image]

It's just the worst part of otherwise very great JBoss Tools plugin.

Comment: The problem got sorted out, Is there any way to use That visual page editor.

Comment: You're welcome. I strongly recommend to not use any visual editor for code.

Comment: I saw your profile page on ZEEF u have given nice tutorial. I want ask u something, I really want to be a good developer in Servlet jsp spring. I started working  in a small from there is no one to help. since i am a fresher i face lot of problem understand these technology. Could you please tell me how do i start or which book should I follow. Please reply

Comment: As to Servlets+JSP, start here: https://servlets.zeef.com. As to Spring, I don't do Spring. I just use standard Java EE stack. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7295697 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379228

Comment: @BalusC, why you prefer standard EE stack over Spring?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a visual editor, I would recommend the XULRunner JBoss tool.

Link to the eclipse update site:

- http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/integration/luna/core/xulrunner/xulrunner-1.9.2_win64-2014-08-22_09-55-58-B4/